# How do I implement an equals method in this exercice (Java)

Tags: java

There are 2 Classes: Loja (Store) and Produto (Product)

The class Produto has 3 children: DVD, CD and Livro, but they all have in common the following attribute: codigoBarras (barCode)

The question is: how do I check if two *produtos* have the same codigoBarras?

```
public class Loja {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        DVD[] dvds = new DVD[5];
        CD[] cds = new CD[5];
        Livro[] livros = new Livro[5];
        Produto[] produtos = new Produto[5];
        int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0, opção;

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        for (int a=0; a<5 ; a++){

            System.out.println("Digite: \n\t 1 - CD \n\t 2 - DVD \n\t 3 - Livro");
            opção = input.nextInt();

            switch(opção){
                case 1:
                    CD cd1 = new CD();
                    System.out.println("\nDigite o nome: ");
                    cd1.setNome(input.next());
                    System.out.println("\nDigite o preço: ");
                    cd1.setPreço(input.nextDouble());
                    System.out.println("\nDigite o numero de faixas: ");
                    cd1.setNumeroFaixas(input.nextInt());
                    produtos[i++] = cd1;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    DVD dvd1 = new DVD();
                    System.out.println("\nDigite o nome: ");
                    dvd1.setNome(input.next());
                    System.out.println("\nDigite o preço: ");
                    dvd1.setPreço(input.nextDouble());
                    System.out.println("\nDigite a duração: ");
                    dvd1.setDuração(input.nextInt());
                    produtos[i++] = dvd1;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    Livro livro1 = new Livro();
                    System.out.println("\nDigite o nome: ");
                    livro1.setNome(input.next());
                    System.out.println("\nDigite o preço: ");
                    livro1.setPreço(input.nextDouble());
                    System.out.println("\nDigite o autor: ");
                    livro1.setAutor(input.next());
                    produtos[i++] = livro1;
                    break;   
                default: 
            }
        }  

        for (int b=0; b<i; b++){
            System.out.println("\n"+produtos[b]);
        }

    }
}

public class Produto {

    private double preço;
    private String nome;
    private long codigoBarras;

    public Produto(double preço, String nome, long codigoBarras){
        this.preço = preço;
        this.nome = nome;  
    }

    public Produto(){}

    public double getPreço() {
        return preço;
    }

    public void setPreço(double preço) {
        this.preço = preço;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public long getCodigoBarras() {
        return codigoBarras;
    }

    public void setCodigoBarras(long codigoBarras) {
        this.codigoBarras = codigoBarras;
    }  


    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return "Produto: ( " + "Nome: " + nome + ", Preço: "+ preço + ")";
    }    

    public void imprimir(){
        System.out.println("Produto: ( " + ", Nome: " + nome + ", Preço: "+ preço + ")");
    }   
}
```

Comment: `@Override public boolean equals(Object o) { return ((Produto) o).getCodingoBarras() == getCodingBarras(); }` - Checks if the passed object, cast to `Produto`, has same barcode as current instance.

Comment: Provide an overridden implementation of the `equals` method. Check the docs for more info.

Comment: If your class has subclasses (DVD, CD, Livro), your problem could be _much_ more difficult.  I think that if the bar code is the only thing you're comparing in _all_ those cases, the simple answer will work.  If you're planning on comparing other fields, things can get messy.  See http://www.artima.com/lejava/articles/equality.html, particularly the part that discusses equivalence relationships.

Comment: The only field that i'm comparing is the bar code. I don't understand how to implement this.. I know I have to compare two objects, but only one of its parameters. Now, I don't know how to call the Objects that i'll be using to compare becouse they have not been created yet. If you understand what I'm asking, I'd apreciate an answer, thank you

Answer (score 0):

In your equals method, you'd just compare the `produto`s' `codigoBarras` for equality (after making sure it is indeed a `Produto`):

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object other) {
    if (other == null || !(other instanceof Produto)) return false;
    Produto p = (Produto)other;
    return codigoBarras == p.codigoBarras;
}
```

Note that this is only possible because `codigoBarras` is a long (value type). If it were a reference type, we'd use its `equals` method to check for equality.

As was mentioned in comments, if you override `equals` you should override `hashCode`as well.

Comment: I used a try-catch for the cast to avoid throwing from equals method. Some disagree with this approach. I think it better captures the essence of equals. Anything that isn't a produto is not equal to any produto.

Comment: Personally, I think `other instanceof Produto` is more concise and readable than casting it within a try-catch

Comment: @qxz feel free to edit that in. Alwayd forget java has it, coming from c# `is` and `as` operators

Comment: @EduardoVieira so you just use getCodigoBarras on each product and compare using ==

Comment: @Eduardo: Why don't you put in a little effort and tweak the answer to your needs.  It's bad enough that you are asking people to do the work for you without having provided any attempts yourself.

Comment: I am trying to solve this exercice for 4 and a half hours, and I got to this point where I can no longer progress

Comment: I really should downvote this for not mentioning that you also need to override `hashCode`.

Comment: @ajb how you vote is your business, though i believe my answer adequately answers the question as posed. I do agree with implementing hash code, and would welcome an edit to that effect. Alternately, feel free to leave your own answer